# How would I make only one function run when i import a python file?

Tags: python

I am trying to import a file and make sure only one function runs. here is the file i am importing:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os




def MainMenu():

        
    MainMenuWin=Tk()
    MainMenuWin.title("Main Menu")
    MainMenuWin.geometry("200x200")
    
    frame1=Frame(MainMenuWin)
    frame1.pack()
                           
    btn1=Button(frame1,text="Add Staff",command=AddStaff)
    btn2=Button(frame1,text="Payroll",command= Payroll)
    
    frame2=Frame(MainMenuWin)
    frame2.pack()

    btn3=Button(frame2,text="Add User",command=AddUser)
    
    frame3=Frame(MainMenuWin)
    frame3.pack()

    btn4=Button(frame3,text="Logout",command=LoginScreen)
    btn5=Button(frame3,text="Exit",command=MainMenuWin.destroy)
            
    btn1.pack()
    btn2.pack()
    btn3.pack()
    btn4.pack(side=LEFT)
    btn5.pack(side=LEFT)
            
def Payroll():
    
    os.system('python Payroll.py')
    
def AddStaff():

    def SaveStaff() :

        StaffIDSave = StaffIDVar.get()
        StaffIDSave = StaffIDSave.ljust(50)
    
        FirstnameSave = FirstnameVar.get()
        FirstnameSave = FirstnameSave.ljust(50)
    
        SurnameSave = SurnameVar.get()
        SurnameSave = SurnameSave.ljust(50)
    
        AddressSave = AddressVar.get()
        AddressSave = AddressSave.ljust(50)
    
        PostCodeSave = PostCodeVar.get()
        PostCodeSave = PostCodeSave.ljust(50)

      
    
        fileObject = open("StaffDetails.txt","a")
        
        fileObject.write(StaffIDSave + FirstnameSave + SurnameSave + AddressSave + PostCodeSave + "\n")
        fileObject.close()
        
        messagebox.showinfo("Confirmation","Staff details successfully saved")
    
    AddStaffWin=Tk()
    AddStaffWin.title("Add Staff")
    AddStaffWin.geometry("300x300")
    
    frame1=Frame(AddStaffWin)
    frame1.pack()

       
    Label(frame1, text="StaffID").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
    StaffIDVar=StringVar()
    StaffIDVar= Entry(frame1, textvariable=StaffIDVar)
    StaffIDVar.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W)

    Label(frame1, text="Firstname").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
    FirstnameVar=StringVar()
    FirstnameVar= Entry(frame1, textvariable=FirstnameVar)
    FirstnameVar.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W)
    
    Label(frame1, text="Surname").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
    SurnameVar=StringVar()
    SurnameVar= Entry(frame1, textvariable=SurnameVar)
    SurnameVar.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=W)
    
    Label(frame1, text="Address").grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
    AddressVar=StringVar()
    AddressVar= Entry(frame1, textvariable=AddressVar)
    AddressVar.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=W)
    
    Label(frame1, text="Postcode").grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)
    PostCodeVar=StringVar()
    PostCodeVar= Entry(frame1, textvariable=PostCodeVar)
    PostCodeVar.grid(row=7,column=1,sticky=W)

  

    frame2 = Frame(AddStaffWin)
    frame2.pack()
    b1= Button(frame2, text=" Back ", command=AddStaffWin.destroy)
    b2= Button(frame2, text=" Save ", command=SaveStaff)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT); b2.pack(side=LEFT)



    
    

    
def AddUser():
    
    def SaveUser() :

        UserIDSave = UserIDVar.get()
        UserIDSave = UserIDSave.strip()
    
        PasswordSave = PasswordVar.get()
        PasswordSave = PasswordSave.strip()
    
       
        fileObject = open("data.dat","a")
        
        fileObject.write(UserIDSave + " " + PasswordSave + "\n")
        fileObject.close()
        
        messagebox.showinfo("Confirmation","Password successfully saved")
    
    AddUserWin=Tk()
    AddUserWin.title("Add User")
    AddUserWin.geometry("300x300")
    
    frame1=Frame(AddUserWin)
    frame1.pack()

       
    Label(frame1, text="UserID").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
    UserIDVar=StringVar()
    UserIDVar= Entry(frame1, textvariable=UserIDVar)
    UserIDVar.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W)

    Label(frame1, text="Password").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
    PasswordVar=StringVar()
    PasswordVar= Entry(frame1, textvariable=PasswordVar)
    PasswordVar.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W)
    
     

    frame2 = Frame(AddUserWin)
    frame2.pack()
    b1= Button(frame2, text=" Back ", command=AddUserWin.destroy)
    b2= Button(frame2, text=" Save ", command=SaveUser)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT); b2.pack(side=LEFT)

    
    
def LoginScreen():
    
    def login():
        username=usname.get()
        passwd=password.get()
        flag=TRUE#3)b)this value can only have two values - true or false- and is used when ensuring the password/username is correct

        if username.strip() == "" and passwd.strip() == "":#3)c) the line of code undernetah this one will only run if the user has left the username and password blank
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Blank username and password")
        elif passwd.strip() == "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Blank password")
        elif username.strip()== "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Blank username")
        else:
            
            passwordfile = open("data.dat","r")
            passvar = passwordfile.readline()
                            
            while flag and passvar !="":#3)a)the part of indented code underneath this line will repeat until the correct username and password is used
                                      
                if passvar.find(username.strip()) >=0 and passvar.find(passwd.strip())>=0:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Authenticated","Correct username and password")
                    flag = FALSE
                                    
                passvar = passwordfile.readline()
                                
                passwordfile.close()
                if flag:
                 messagebox.showinfo("Error","Incorrect username and / or password")
                else:
                    loginwindow.destroy()
                    MainMenu()
                                

        
    loginwindow=Tk()
    loginwindow.title("Log In Screen")
    loginwindow.geometry("200x200")
    lbluname=Label(loginwindow, text="Username")
    usname=Entry(loginwindow)
    lblpass=Label(loginwindow, text="Password")
    password=Entry(loginwindow)

    lbluname.pack()
    usname.pack()
    lblpass.pack()
    password.pack()

    btn=Button(loginwindow,text="Log In",command=login).pack()


LoginScreen()
```

And here is the program importing this file:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

win = Tk()

def back():
    import ParkWoodGYM
    ParkWoodGYM.MainMenu()
    win.destroy()

back = Button(text = "Back", command = back).pack()
```

As you can see I tried running just the `MainMenu()` function in the second code as that's what I want to see singularly yet it didn't work.

Comment: There is too much code here to work through it all; it would be better to present a simple example demonstrating the current issue rather than expecting us to debug all your code, "Did not work" does not tell us much. What do you intend to happen when you call `os.system('python Payroll.py')` ?

Comment: @user190778851 sorry its unclear the payroll is another file, all i really need is to understand how i can edit the bottom code so that when i press the back button it only runs the MainMenu() function and not the whole code, if i should edit the question in any way just tell me

Comment: You used multiple instance of Tk()

Comment: If you don't want import to have side effects, that's what an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard is for

Comment: It's irrelevant with the question, but here's a general advice. Use your free time to learn how to write idiomatic and readable code and then play around with frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

When importing a file, always remember that everything there gets executed.
So when you import your first bit of code, the import statement will automatically execute

```py
LoginScreen()
```

because you put that code at the end of the file. Thus, when you execute the program importing this file, the login screen gets opened, then subsequently the main menu gets opened. If you would like to prevent this, try the following at the end of the first file:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginScreen()
```

Here the login screen only opens if you are running the first piece of code, and not if you import the file.